# Adding values in a YAML file via loop

Tags: bash, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-facts

As a part of the Kubernetes Resource Definition, I want to whitelist certain IPs. The list of IPs can be found by

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide --no-headers | awk '{print $7}'
#This prints something like
51.52.215.214
18.170.74.10
.....
```

Now,
In the Kubernetes deployment file (say deployment.yaml) I want to loop over these values and whitelist them.
I know that we can whitelist by adding under loadBalancerSourceRanges like

```
#part of the deployment.yaml
loadBalancerSourceRanges
 - 51.52.112.111
 - 18.159.75.11
```

I want to update the above loadBalancerSourceRanges to include the output of
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide --no-headers | awk '{print $7}'

How do I go about it? Instead of hardcoding the host IPs, I would like to programatically include via bash or ansible or any other cleaner way possible.

Thanks in advance,
JE

Comment: Please add more details, the full `deployment` file could be usefull. Using a tool like [tag:yq] this can't be that hard.

Comment: @java_enthu Already provided 3 answers. Are any of them useful?  Consider accepting the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solves your issue.

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin appreciate your "gentle reminder" :-) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadBalancerSourceRanges` should be a part of Service, not Deployment

You can use the following oneliner to patch your service dynamically:

`kubectl patch service YOUR_SERVICE_NAME -p "{\"spec\":{\"loadBalancerSourceRanges\": [$(kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*].status.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIP")]}"{.address}/32",{end}' | sed 's/,*$//g')]}}"`

, where you should replace `YOUR_SERVICE_NAME` with actual service name

To explain what's going on here:

We are using `kubectl patch` to patch existing resource, in our case - `spec.loadBalancerSourceRanges`.

- we are putting our subshell inside `[$(..)]`, since  `loadBalancerSourceRanges` requires array of strings
- `kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*].status.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIP")]}"{.address}/32",{end}'` - gets InternalIPs from your nodes, adds `/32` to each of them, since `loadBalancerSourceRanges` requires *ranges*, encloses each range in `"` and  then places coma between each value.
- `sed 's/,*$//g'` - removes a trailing comma

Using jsonpath is better thatn awk/cut because we are not dependent on kubectl column ordering and get only relevant for us information from API.

I agree with @Kaffe Myers that you should try using kustomize or helm or other templating engines, since they should be a better suited for this job.

Comment: This looks good. I will give it a go. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)

```
# empty array if necessary
yq -i '.loadBalancerSourceRanges = []' file.yaml

# In my env (AWS EKS) the IP is field 6 (change if needed)
for host in $(kubectl get nodes -o wide --no-headers | awk '{print $6}')
do
  yq -i '.loadBalancerSourceRanges += ["'${host}'"]' file.yaml
done
```

1. The -i parameter is to apply the change to the file (like sed)
2. If *"loadBalancerSourceRanges"* is inside *"config"*, you can use: *".config.loadBalancerSourceRanges"*

Answer (score 0):

This is a very use-specific thingy, and you might be better off researching [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/). That being said, you could make a temporary file which you alter before deploy.

```sh
cp deployment.yaml temp.yaml
kubectl get nodes -o wide --no-headers |
    awk '{print $7}' |
    xargs -I{} sed -Ei "s/^(\s+)(loadBalancerSourceRanges:)/\1\2\n\1  - {}/" temp.yaml

kubectl apply -f temp.yaml
```

It looks for the `loadBalancerSourceRanges:` part of the yaml, which on the "template" shouldn't have any values, then populate it with whatever `kubectl get nodes -o wide --no-headers | awk '{print $7}'` feeds it with.